# Rails 3, Internationalization (I18n) - Translate number to value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have a user table with a level column. The level column is numeric and the value is 0, 1, or  2.

Is there anyway to get the Internationalization (I18n) API to convert the numeric value so that in english 0 = Foobar, 1 = Foo, 2 = Bar? Then in another language 0,1,2 could return something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found you can do this by adding something like the following to your locales files:

```
en:
  user:
    level:
      '0': 'Admin'
      '1': 'Editor'
      '2': 'Contributer'
```

Then in a view:

```
<%= f.select :level, (0..2).to_a.map { |level| [t(level, :scope => 'user.level'), level] } %>
```

There might be a better way, but this seem to be working well for me!